# Unable to read image from path (/tmp/phpjRWxLB) caused by Imagick

Tags: ubuntu, cakephp, imagick

This error is bothering me for far too long now.

I am using cakephp 3.4 with and ImageUpload plugin.
Everything worked fine untill suddenly I started getting

`502 bad gateway` Error

As I check my cakephp logs I can see this:

```
Error: [Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException] Unable to read image from path (/tmp/phpjRWxLB).

Caused by: [ImagickException] no decode delegate for this image format `JPEG' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/504
```

I didn`t do any server updates but it seems that Imagick is haveing trouble of reading an image or something.

What did I try:
I wanted to check `phpinfo()` but if I do that I got `502 bad gateway` again

I tried to update `imagick` but still nothing.

Also if I do

```
php -i | grep php.ini
```

response is:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path => /etc/php/7.2/cli
Loaded Configuration File => /etc/php/7.2/cli/php.ini
double free or corruption (out)
Magick: abort due to signal 6 (SIGABRT) "Abort"...
```

Any idea what the hell is going on here?

Comment: Something on the server is conflicting with Imagick. You need to find that in the logs. or maybe just try to restart the apache on the server once.